# Proving by Contrapositive (specific question within)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-explanation

I'm having issues coming up with a contrapositive proof for the following question.

As far as I know, a proof by contraposition is based on the following :

> $\overline Q \to \overline P \equiv P \to Q$

or that's where I'm mistaken?

The question is:

> X,Y,Z are natural numbers.
>   if $X^3+Y^3=Z^3$ , then at least one of them is divisible by 3.
>   Provide a proof by contrapositive.

I've tried to substitude X,Y,Z with (3A-1),(3B-1),(3C-1) , essentially trying to get to a point where:

$\overline Q$ : none is divisble by 3 (3N-1).

$\overline P$ : $X^3+Y^3\neq Z^3$

$\overline Q$ -> $\overline P$ $\equiv$ P -> Q

I tried to simplify the equation but it doesn't look like I got anywhere, where am I being wrong?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You assumed that a number **not** divisible by $3$ must be of the form $3N-1$. What about $4$ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I should have written it specifically, my professor gave me that idea, what other route can I go to solve this?
Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: I think if you consider x,y,z individually in form that is not divisible by 3 i.e., 3n-1 and 3n-2, you would have total 27 permutations of these numbers and you would have 27 cases to prove. So I think you should think of a different approach.

Comment: Have you learned about the modulo notation in your course?

Comment: @F.Carette
By modulo notation are you referring to the remainder?
If I remember correctly, it's symbol is %, and 6%7 = 1?

Comment: @Jimmy
Yeah it's probably one of the reasons I got stuck, also Mauro says it's wrong to assume (3N-1) is valid for all the numbers not divisible by 3.

as for Fermet's last theorem, I'm aware of it but I can't use it when proving.

Comment: That's the symbol used in programming languages. In mathematics we write $7\equiv 1\pmod 6$. Anyway, I had an idea of a proof using it, but it didn't turn up to be as easy as I thought

Comment: @Jimmy How are you counting them to get to 27? There's only 6 meaningfully different cases: $(X,Y,Z) \equiv (-1,-1,-1), (1,-1,-1),(-1,-1,1), (1,1,-1),(1,-1,1),(1,1,1) \mod 3$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't paid attention to that.

Comment: Hmmm, so far regarding how contrapositive should be and my initial plan of proof as written above, am I going the right way?

Comment: Maybe this will help. You can write $X^3=Xmod(3)$, whenever $X$ is not divisible by 3.

Comment: Can it help with a contrapositive proof?
I can't think of how to work it out with Modulo :/

Comment: For a contrapositive proof, you have to assume that none of them is divisible by $3$ and deduce a contradiction.  Looking at congruence classes tells you that there are two cases to consider: $X\equiv Y\equiv1\pmod{3}$ and  $X\equiv Y\equiv2\pmod{3}$  In the first case, $Z\equiv2\pmod{3}$ and in the second $Z\equiv1\pmod{3}$  There's no contradiction here, though, so the proof must lie deeper.

Comment: For positive integers, that equation is always false.

Comment: I think we can actually reduce the cases to just one: $X \equiv Y \equiv 1 $ (mod 3). For any $k \in N$, $X^3 + Y^3 = Z^3$ if and only if $(kX)^3 + (kY)^3 = (kZ)^3$. This means that $X^3 + Y^3 = Z^3$ is a solution and $X \equiv Y \equiv 1 $ (mod 3) if and only if $(2X)^3 + (2Y)^3 = (2Z)^3$ is a solution and $2X \equiv 2Y \equiv -1 $ (mod 3). So a negative result for $X \equiv Y \equiv 1 $ (mod 3) implies a negative result for $X \equiv Y \equiv -1 $ (mod 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments, if we have $X, Y$ and $Z$ none of which are divisible by 3 and such that $X^3 + Y^3 = Z^3$, we may assume that $X,Y \equiv 1$ (mod 3) and $Z \equiv 2$ (mod 3). So, we may assume that there are $a$ $b$ and $c$ such that $X = 3a+1$, $Y = 3b+1$ and $Z = 3c+2$. By applying the binomial expansion to $X^3$ and $Y^3$, it turns out that $X^3 \equiv 1$ (mod 9) and $Y^3 \equiv 1$ (mod 9), so that $X^3 + Y^3 \equiv 2$ (mod 9). But if you apply the binomial expansion to $Z^3 = (3c+2)^3$, it turns out that $Z^3 \equiv 8$ (mod 9). Thus, the equality $X^3 + Y^3 = Z^3$ cannot hold.